# Smiles2Monomers build fails

Tags: java, build, package, ant

I am trying to use the Java software package https://github.com/yoann-dufresne/Smiles2Monomers on a Windows 10 computer. The installation worked fine until running the `ant preCompute` command which returns:

```
C:\Users\elabi\Smiles2Monomers>ant preCompute
Buildfile: C:\Users\elabi\Smiles2Monomers\build.xml

preCompute:
     [java] JVM args ignored when same JVM is used.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\elabi\Smiles2Monomers\build.xml:81: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
        at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:425)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.types.Permissions.setSecurityManager(Permissions.java:103)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:216)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:155)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:891)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:231)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:818)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I posted an issue and their GitHub but doubt there will be a solution since the package has not been updated in 5 years, but if they answer I will post the solution also here. Does anybody know why the build fails and how I could still get it running?

I have Java version 8 (build 1.8.0_351-b10), jdk-19 and jre1.8.0_351.

Comment: You might do well to indicate your installed Java version. It's likely you'll have to install an earlier version to build without issues.

Comment: I have updated the question with the Java versions

Comment: Your Java versions don't seem to align with each other. JDK 19 is installed, yet "java -version" points to Java 8? And you still have a JRE installed? I would start by uninstalling JDK (including removing references to JDK 19 from PATH) and trying. If all else fails, nuke all Java from orbit (delete and reinstall only jJava 8) -- it's the only way to be sure.